# My marble coated pan is scratched, still safe to use?

Tags: cookware, pan, non-stick

Recently, I noticed that there seem to be scratches on my pan. And the scratches looks brownish. The pan is a non-stick marble coated pan, and here is the picture of my pan, with scratches on it. May I know if it is still safe to be used?

[image]
[image]