# My marble coated pan is scratched, is it safe to use?

Tags: cookware, frying-pan, non-stick

Related to [My marble coated pan is scratched, still safe to use?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/124754/my-marble-coated-pan-is-scratched-still-safe-to-use)
But the question was never answered. It was closed and the answer was redirected to answers about Teflon pans and ceramic pans, both of which are very different. So I will ask again for myself and everyone else still waiting for an actual answer- is a marble coated pan with scratches or chips still safe to use? Is there any way to repair it?

Comment: What makes you think that reposting a closed answer will lead to a different result?

Comment: Please clarify how a „marble coated“ pan differs significantly from the linked ones.

Comment: “Marble” is a color effect. It’s not real marble, it’s a normal ceramic coating.

Comment: In this case, calling it ‘marble’ is misleading.  I'd call it ‘marbled’, or ‘marble-effect’.  (Real marble is too porous to be suitable for cookware — even if it could be applied as a coating.)